# Netflix Zuul Pre Filter for Cache is not working for a smal amount of compressed responses

Tags: java, caching, netflix-zuul

I'd like to use **zuul** to cache some requests. The Cache is stored in a **Redis** as a **POJO** and contains plaintext (not gzip compressed data).

For normal tests and integration tests, everything works pretty well. With a jmeter load test, some of the requests fails with

```
java.util.zip.ZipException: Not in GZIP format (from jmeter)
```

We figure out, that at this point, zuul is returning an empty response.

**My PreFilter:**

```
public class CachePreFilter extends CacheBaseFilter {

    private static DynamicIntProperty INITIAL_STREAM_BUFFER_SIZE = DynamicPropertyFactory.getInstance().getIntProperty(ZuulConstants.ZUUL_INITIAL_STREAM_BUFFER_SIZE, 8192);

    @Autowired
    CounterService counterService;

    public CachePreFilter(RedisCacheManager redisCacheManager, Properties properties) {
        super(redisCacheManager, properties);
    }

    @Override
    public Object run() {
        RequestContext ctx = RequestContext.getCurrentContext();

        CachedResponse data = getFromCache(ctx);
        if (null != data) {

            counterService.increment("counter.cached");

            HttpServletResponse response = ctx.getResponse();

            response.addHeader("X-Cache", "HIT");

            if (null != data.getContentType()) {
                response.setContentType(data.getContentType());
            }

            if (null != data.getHeaders()) {
                for (Entry<String, String> header : data.getHeaders().entrySet()) {
                    if (!response.containsHeader(header.getKey())) {
                        response.addHeader(header.getKey(), header.getValue());
                    }
                }
            }

            OutputStream outStream = null;
            try {
                outStream = response.getOutputStream();

                boolean isGzipRequested = ctx.isGzipRequested();

                if (null != data.getBody()) {
                    final String requestEncoding = ctx.getRequest().getHeader(ZuulHeaders.ACCEPT_ENCODING);

                    if (requestEncoding != null && HTTPRequestUtils.getInstance().isGzipped(requestEncoding)) {
                        isGzipRequested = true;
                    }

                    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = null;
                    ByteArrayInputStream is = null;
                    try {

                        if (isGzipRequested) {
                            byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                            GZIPOutputStream gzipOutputStream = new GZIPOutputStream(byteArrayOutputStream);
                            gzipOutputStream.write(data.getBody().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
                            gzipOutputStream.flush();
                            gzipOutputStream.close();

                            ctx.setResponseGZipped(true);

                            is = new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray());
                            logger.debug(String.format("Send gzip content %s", data.getBody()));

                            response.setHeader(ZuulHeaders.CONTENT_ENCODING, "gzip");
                        } else {
                            logger.debug(String.format("Send content %s", data.getBody()));

                            is = new ByteArrayInputStream(data.getBody().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
                        }
                        writeResponse(is, outStream);

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        logger.error("Error at sending response " + e.getMessage(), e);
                        throw new RuntimeException("Failed to send content", e);
                    } finally {
                        if (null != byteArrayOutputStream) {
                            byteArrayOutputStream.close();
                        }

                        if (null != is) {
                            is.close();
                        }
                    }
                }

                ctx.setSendZuulResponse(false);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                logger.error("Cannot read from Stream " + e.getMessage(), e.getMessage());
            } finally {
                // don't close the outputstream
            }

            ctx.set(CACHE_HIT, true);

            return data;
        } else {
            counterService.increment("counter.notcached");
        }

        ctx.set(CACHE_HIT, false);
        return null;
    }

    private ThreadLocal<byte[]> buffers = new ThreadLocal<byte[]>() {
        @Override
        protected byte[] initialValue() {
            return new byte[INITIAL_STREAM_BUFFER_SIZE.get()];
        }
    };

    private void writeResponse(InputStream zin, OutputStream out) throws Exception {
        byte[] bytes = buffers.get();
        int bytesRead = -1;
        while ((bytesRead = zin.read(bytes)) != -1) {
            out.write(bytes, 0, bytesRead);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int filterOrder() {
        return 99;
    }

    @Override
    public String filterType() {
        return "pre";
    }
}
```

**My Post Filter**

```
public class CachePostFilter extends CacheBaseFilter {

    public CachePostFilter(RedisCacheManager redisCacheManager, Properties properties) {
        super(redisCacheManager, properties);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldFilter() {
        RequestContext ctx = RequestContext.getCurrentContext();
        return super.shouldFilter() && !ctx.getBoolean(CACHE_HIT);
    }

    @Override
    public Object run() {
        RequestContext ctx = RequestContext.getCurrentContext();
        HttpServletRequest req = ctx.getRequest();
        HttpServletResponse res = ctx.getResponse();

        if (isSuccess(res, ctx.getOriginResponseHeaders())) {
            // Store only successful responses

            String cacheKey = cacheKey(req);
            if (cacheKey != null) {
                String body = null;

                if (null != ctx.getResponseBody()) {
                    body = ctx.getResponseBody();
                } else if (null != ctx.getResponseDataStream()) {
                    InputStream is = null;
                    try {
                        is = ctx.getResponseDataStream();

                        final Long len = ctx.getOriginContentLength();
                        if (len == null || len > 0) {

                            if (ctx.getResponseGZipped()) {
                                is = new GZIPInputStream(is);
                            }

                            StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();

                            IOUtils.copy(is, writer, "UTF-8");
                            body = writer.toString();

                            if (null != body && !body.isEmpty()) {
                                ctx.setResponseDataStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(body.getBytes()));
                                ctx.setResponseGZipped(false);
                                ctx.setOriginContentLength(String.valueOf(body.getBytes().length));
                            } else {
                                ctx.setResponseBody("{}");
                            }
                        }

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        logger.error("Cannot read body " + e.getMessage(), e);
                    } finally {
                        if (null != is) {
                            try {
                                is.close();
                            } catch (IOException e) {

                            }
                        }
                    }

                    saveToCache(ctx, cacheKey, body);
                }
            }
        }
        return null;

    }

    @Override
    public int filterOrder() {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public String filterType() {
        return "post";
    }

    private boolean isSuccess(HttpServletResponse res, List<Pair<String, String>> originHeaders) {
        if (res != null && res.getStatus() < 300) {
            if (null != originHeaders) {
                for (Pair<String, String> header : originHeaders) {
                    if (header.first().equals("X-CACHEABLE") && header.second().equals("1")) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

We test it without **Redis** (just store it into a local variable) and this is still the same. We logged always the response from cache (before gzip) and everything looks good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(Posted on behalf of the question author)*.

**Solution**

We refactor our PostFilter and don't change so much in the Response for zuul. After this change, we don't see any problems any more:

**Working Post Filter**

```
public class CachePostFilter extends CacheBaseFilter {

    public CachePostFilter(RedisCacheManager redisCacheManager, Properties properties) {
        super(redisCacheManager, properties);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldFilter() {
        RequestContext ctx = RequestContext.getCurrentContext();
        return super.shouldFilter() && !ctx.getBoolean(CACHE_HIT);
    }

    @Override
    public Object run() {
        RequestContext ctx = RequestContext.getCurrentContext();
        HttpServletRequest req = ctx.getRequest();
        HttpServletResponse res = ctx.getResponse();

        if (isSuccess(res, ctx.getOriginResponseHeaders())) {
            // Store only successful responses

            String cacheKey = cacheKey(req);
            if (cacheKey != null) {
                String body = null;

                if (null != ctx.getResponseBody()) {
                    body = ctx.getResponseBody();
                } else if (null != ctx.getResponseDataStream()) {
                    InputStream rawInputStream = null;
                    InputStream gzipByteArrayInputStream = null;
                    try {
                        rawInputStream = ctx.getResponseDataStream();
                        gzipByteArrayInputStream = null;
                        // If origin tell it's GZipped but the content is ZERO
                        // bytes,
                        // don't try to uncompress
                        final Long len = ctx.getOriginContentLength();
                        if (len == null || len > 0) {

                            byte[] rawData = IOUtils.toByteArray(rawInputStream);

                            ctx.setResponseDataStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(rawData));

                            if (ctx.getResponseGZipped()) {
                                gzipByteArrayInputStream = new GZIPInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(rawData));
                            } else {
                                gzipByteArrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(rawData);
                            }

                            StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();

                            IOUtils.copy(gzipByteArrayInputStream, writer, "UTF-8");
                            body = writer.toString();
                        }

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        logger.error("Cannot read body " + e.getMessage(), e);
                    } finally {
                        if (null != rawInputStream) {
                            try {
                                rawInputStream.close();
                            } catch (IOException e) {

                            }
                        }

                        if (null != gzipByteArrayInputStream) {
                            try {
                                gzipByteArrayInputStream.close();
                            } catch (IOException e) {

                            }
                        }
                    }

                    // if we read from the stream, the other filter cannot read
                    // and they dont' deliver any response
                    // ctx.setResponseBody(body);
                    // ctx.setResponseGZipped(false);

                    saveToCache(ctx, cacheKey, body);
                }
            }
        }
        return null;

    }

    @Override
    public int filterOrder() {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public String filterType() {
        return "post";
    }

    private boolean isSuccess(HttpServletResponse res, List<Pair<String, String>> originHeaders) {
        if (res != null && res.getStatus() == 200) {
            if (null != originHeaders) {
                for (Pair<String, String> header : originHeaders) {
                    if (header.first().equals("X-CACHEABLE") && header.second().equals("1")) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```